# System.runtime.InteropServices.Comexception Microsoft Interop C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm receiving this error when writing to an excel sheet in C#. After writing 4,500 rows an error pops up:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800AC472): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472
>     at System.Dynamic.ComRuntimeHelpers.CheckThrowException(Int32 hresult, ExcepInfo& excepInfo, UInt32 argErr, String message)
>     at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , ComObject , String )
>     at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String )
>     at PaymentVarReadPDFMurfreesboro.ConvertPdfToExcel.writeToExcel(String filePath)

Here is the code that opens and writes to excel.

```
public void writeToExcel(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        ExcelUse.Application excel = new ExcelUse.Application();
        excel.Visible = true;
        excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
        ExcelUse.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
        ExcelUse.Worksheet sh2 = wb.Worksheets.get_Item("Sheet1");

        for (int i = 2; i <= finalList.Count+1; i++)
        {
            sh2.Cells[i, "A"].Value2 = finalList[i-2].ToString().Substring(33, 8);
            sh2.Cells[i, "B"].Value2 = finalList[i-2].ToString().Substring(44, 7);
            sh2.Cells[i, "C"].Value2 = finalList[i-2].ToString().Substring(117, 7);
        }

        wb.Save();
        wb.Close(true);
        excel.Quit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

I've used this code before to write to excel sheets. Yet for some reason it's not working. I think it has something to do with how many rows it's writing too.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411016/c-sharp-excel-interop-alternatives-to-waiting-to-handle-0x800ac472-error  It looks like its busy.  Maybe related to other CPU load at the time or the number of rows. See this blog for some tips to reduce overhead on Excel automation http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/ten-things-you-can-do-to-speed-up-your-excel-vba-code/

Comment: uh the few simple tricks might have worked.

Comment: They do wonders.  If you do not need to interact with Excel, and just need to modify existing files, and only need to work with XLSX files, also try the EPPlus library.  It is much more performant and doesn't require an instance of Excel running.

Comment: Yeah it worked. Just takes so long to write 8800 lines. I might have to look into EPPlus next script.